# Having two baud rates in one arduino code

Tags: arduino, baud-rate

I have an arduino code for many different sensors connected to MEGA, one of them is the bluetooth, is that possible to make the bluetooth run with a different baudrate than the other sensors?

Comment: do you have only one serial port?  cant you use diffrent serial port for bluetooth? if hardware dosent have more than one serial port, we can always use softwareserial

Comment: Yes i have two serial ports, so is that possible to use serial1 for the bluetooth and serial for the other sensors in one code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not limited to using only hardware serial port in arduino. you can use softwareserial library to emulate serial port in other pins too.

In your case you can have bluetooth connected to your arduino serial port and other sensor connected to software serial port. This way you can have different `baud rates` for diffrent device.